# Power BI Custom Visual : Colour Change when modify date slicer

Tags: typescript, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I created a custom visual in power BI that allowed to insert different types of chart in one plot. But when I insert the plot on the dashboard, I have some trouble with date slicer. I define a colour for ma data and I save it with:

```js
let view = dataView[0].categorical;
let categories = view.categories[0];
let objects = categories.objects;
let value = view.values;

for (let i = 0, len = Math.max(value.length); i < len; i++) {
  viewModel.dataPoints.push({
    category: < string > value[i].source.displayName,
    colour: objects && objects[i] && DataViewObjects.getFillColor(objects[i], {
      objectName: "colorSelector",
      propertyName: "fill"
    }, null),
    selectionId: this.host.createSelectionIdBuilder()
      .withCategory(categories, i)
      .createSelectionId(),
  });
}
```

But when I change the date slicer, objects is null or undefined and colour is reset to default.

There is a solution to always save the color in object when slicer is modify.

Thanks for yours help.

Comment: Hello, could you share capabilities.json and body of enumerateObjectInstances method? Need to more details to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

enumerateObjectInstances method :

```js
public enumerateObjectInstances(options: EnumerateVisualObjectInstancesOptions): VisualObjectInstanceEnumeration {
 let objectName = options.objectName;
 let objectEnumeration: VisualObjectInstance[] = [];
 let index = 0;
 switch (objectName) {
  case 'xAxis':
   objectEnumeration.push({
    objectName: objectName,
    properties: this.settings.xAxis,
    selector: null
   });
   break;
  case 'y1Axis':
   objectEnumeration.push({
    objectName: objectName,
    properties: this.settings.y1Axis,
    selector: null
   });
   break;
  case 'y2Axis':
   objectEnumeration.push({
    objectName: objectName,
    properties: this.settings.y2Axis,
    selector: null
   });
   break;
  case 'margin':
   objectEnumeration.push({
    objectName: objectName,
    properties: this.settings.margin,
    selector: null
   });
   break;
  case 'legend':
   objectEnumeration.push({
    objectName: objectName,
    properties: this.settings.legend,
    selector: null
   });
   break;
  case 'colorSelector':
   if (this.viewModel) {
    for (let dp of this.viewModel.dataPoints) {
     objectEnumeration.push({
      objectName: objectName,
      displayName: dp.category,
      properties: {
       fill: {
        solid: {
         color: dp.colour || this.settings.colorSelector[Object.keys(this.settings.colorSelector)[index]]
        }
       }
      },
      selector: dp.selectionId.getSelector()
     });
    }
   }
   break;
  case 'datashape':
   if (this.viewModel) {
    for (let dp of this.viewModel.dataPoints) {
     objectEnumeration.push({
      objectName: objectName,
      displayName: dp.category,
      properties: {
       shape: dp.symbol || this.settings.datashape[Object.keys(this.settings.datashape)[index]]
      },
      selector: dp.selectionId.getSelector()
     });
    }
   }
   break;
  case 'datatrace':
   if (this.viewModel) {
    for (let dp of this.viewModel.dataPoints) {
     objectEnumeration.push({
      objectName: objectName,
      displayName: dp.category,
      properties: {
       charttype: dp.trace || this.settings.datatrace[Object.keys(this.settings.datatrace)[index]]
      },
      selector: dp.selectionId.getSelector()
     });
    }
   }
   break;
   };
   return objectEnumeration;
}
```

Capabilities.json :

```js
{
    "dataRoles": [
        {
            "displayName": "X-Axis",
            "name": "x",
            "kind": "Grouping"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Y-Axis 1",
            "name": "y1",
            "kind": "Measure"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Y-Axis 2",
            "name": "y2",
            "kind": "Measure"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Split by",
            "name": "splitby1",
            "kind": "Grouping"
        }
    ],
    "dataViewMappings": [
        {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "x": {
                        "max": 1
                    },
                    "legend": {
                        "max": 1
                    },
                    "splitby1": {
                        "max": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "categorical": {
                "categories": {
                    "for": {
                        "in": "x"
                    }
                },
                "values": {
                    "group": {
                        "by": "splitby1",
                        "select": [
                            {
                                "for": {
                                    "in": "y1"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "for": {
                                    "in": "y2"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "suppressDefaultTitle": true,
    "objects": {
        "xAxis": {
            "displayName": "X-Axis",
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "displayName": "Title",
                    "type": {
                        "text": true
                    }
                },
                "margin": {
                    "displayName": "Margin",
                    "type": {
                        "text": true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "y1Axis": {
            "displayName": "Y1-Axis",
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "displayName": "Title",
                    "type": {
                        "text": true
                    }
                },
                "margin": {
                    "displayName": "Margin",
                    "type": {
                        "text": true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "y2Axis": {
            "displayName": "Y2-Axis",
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "displayName": "Title",
                    "type": {
                        "text": true
                    }
                },
                "margin": {
                    "displayName": "Margin",
                    "type": {
                        "text": true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "datatrace": {
            "displayName": "Trace Type",
            "properties": {
                "charttype": {
                    "displayName": "Trace",
                    "type": {
                        "enumeration": [
                            {
                                "displayName": "Line Chart",
                                "value": "line"
                            },
                            {
                                "displayName": "Line Marker Chart",
                                "value": "lineMarker"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "margin": {
            "displayName": "Margins",
            "properties": {
                "l": {
                    "displayName": "Left",
                    "type": {
                        "numeric": true
                    }
                },
                "r": {
                    "displayName": "Right",
                    "type": {
                        "numeric": true
                    }
                },
                "t": {
                    "displayName": "Top",
                    "type": {
                        "numeric": true
                    }
                },
                "b": {
                    "displayName": "Bottom",
                    "type": {
                        "numeric": true
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "legend": {
            "displayName": "Legend",
            "properties": {
                "enabled": {
                    "displayName": "Enabled",
                    "type": {
                        "bool": true
                    }
                },
                "orientation": {
                    "displayName": "Orientation",
                    "type": {
                        "enumeration": [
                            {
                                "displayName": "Vertical",
                                "value": "v"
                            },
                            {
                                "displayName": "Horizontal",
                                "value": "h"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "colorSelector": {
            "displayName": "Data Colors",
            "properties": {
                "fill": {
                    "displayName": "Color",
                    "type": {
                        "fill": {
                            "solid": {
                                "color": true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "datashape": {
            "displayName": "Shape Type",
            "properties": {
                "shape": {
                    "displayName": "Shape",
                    "type": {
                        "enumeration": [
                            {
                                "displayName": "Default",
                                "value": "none"
                            },
                            {
                                "displayName": "Circle",
                                "value": "circle"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```